# How to stop infinite loop with the same trigger that starts it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, discord, discord.py

So I have something like this:

```
import discord, asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!test"):
        await client.delete_message(message)
        test1 = await client.send_message(message.channel, "%s test1" % (message.author.mention))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        while True:
            #newtest = await client.wait_for_message()
            #if newtest.content.lower().startswith("!test"):
                #return 0
            #else:
                test2 = await client.edit_message(test1, "%s test2" % (message.author.mention))
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                await client.edit_message(test2, "%s test1" % (message.author.mention))
                await asyncio.sleep(1)

client.run('ClientTokenHere')
```

What it does is, if someone types in `!test` into a chat channel, the script will delete that `!test` message, then send a message into the chat that says the person's name followed by the text `test1`. Then the script will edit that message to say `test2` after a second, then it will edit *that* same message to say `test1`, then again to `test2`, etc., etc. forever.

However, I want to make it so that if another user types in the same command `!test` again, the script immediately will stop for the user for whom it was previously activated for, and start doing it for the most recent user who issued the command. The lines that I commented out is my attempts at trying to achieve this. How can do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `asyncio.sleep(1)`, you should use

```py
def check(message):
   return message.channel == ctx.channel and message.content.lower().startswith("!test")

try:
   await client.wait_for('message', timeout=1, check=check)
except:
   continue
```

The only disadvantage that this has is that if the timeout occurs, then until the loops runs again the bot wont listen to commands.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an global variable an set the user who you are following. If the user changes you can break the while loop and stop.